# I am trying to make a function with that returns true/false if an element is in the vector but I am getting an error?

Tags: oop, c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I am trying to implement a function in C++ using STL which takes an object and a vector of objects and return true if the vector contains the object else false. Below is the implementation of the function:

```
bool belongs(vertex V, std::vector<vertex> &array)
{
  std::vector<vertex>::iterator it;
  it = find(array.begin(), array.end(), V);
  if(it != array.end())
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
 invalid operands to binary expression ('vertex' and 'const vertex')
        if (*__first == __value_)
```

What can I do? I am a little new to programming in STL using Object Oriented Programming so your help is awaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is there is no `operator==` defined for vertex type (which `find` needs in order to determine if 2 `vertex` instances are the same). You can define one as follows:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct vertex
{
    float a, b;
    bool operator==(const vertex& o) const // <-- This method is what find is looking for
    {
        return a == o.a && b == o.b;
    }
};

bool belongs(vertex V, const std::vector<vertex>& array)
{
    return find(array.begin(), array.end(), V) != array.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<vertex> v = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << belongs({ 4, 5 }, v);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b985d123cdac9ce)

I've also shortened the implementation of belongs, its much clearer to:

```
return x;
```

rather than:

```
if (x)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: I have made a vertex class, what should I do in that case?

Comment: @DanishAmjadAlvi Implement operator== for it, I didn't have your vertex class so I made one up.